# In Rails on production, redirection is wrong after POST request (working locally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to take a user-inputted email address, store it in the DB, and then send a welcome email to that address. If this is successful, the user should be redirected back to `root`. Locally this is happening correctly, but on my Heroku production server, the address is getting saved in the DB, but the user is then redirected back to `subscribers`. This is the API call for saving a subscriber, but it doesn't have a corresponding view.

The email is also not being sent, although that may be a separate issue. If it matters, I'm trying to use MailGun to send the email.

I'm not sure which of these files are necessary, but...

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  resources :subscribers, only: :create
end
```

**/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:**

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      SubscribeMailer.subscribe_email(@subscriber).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Success! Check your email."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! That's not a valid email."
      redirect_to root_path
    end

  end

  private
    def subscriber_params
      params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email)
    end

end
```

**/models/subscriber.rb:**

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_email_format_of :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

**/mailers/subscriber_mailer.rb:**

```
class SubscribeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "email@gmail.com"
  def subscribe_email(subscriber)
    mail(to: subscriber.email, subject: 'Subject')
  end
end
```

**/config/environment.rb:**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
  :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'subdomain.herokuapp.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

In looking at some other StackOverflow threads, OPs were asked for prod logs. I ran `heroku logs`, but didn't see anything that sticks out.

Comment: I don't think this would be the answer, but I've always seen the root to: 'controller#action' call at the very bottom of your routes.  

The logs would be helpful to see exactly what is happening, though.

Comment: i think you have to check form `action` may be there is static typed URL which cause  this  issue

Comment: Based on what you explained it sounds like ".deliver is failing" which is why the redirect never makes it.  Do you have mailgun variables set up correctly on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I was using a sandbox domain for Mailgun, and the email I was testing with wasn't the same one I authorized for use through Mailgun.